# Show that a set is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $D(k)$ is an increasing sequence and 
$D\overset{k}{\rightarrow} A$, where $A$ is a constant real.

We have to show that the set

$\{k | D \leq Q < A\}$ is bounded ? where $Q$ is a constant real.

In the original proof, they don't give any details about the proof, it seems like straightforward. But I'm not sure to undestand which rule they apply for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $D(k) \to A$ then for any $\varepsilon >0 $ the set $\{k| D(k) \leq A-\varepsilon \}$ is finite and hence bounded. So if we set $\varepsilon =A-Q$ then we obtain that the set $\{k| D(k)\leq Q\}$ is finite.

Comment: I'm not sure to see how you can directly deduce that the set $\{k|D(k) \leq A - \varepsilon \}$ is finite?

Answer (score 0):

Renewed Answer:

You don't even need the fact that $D(k)$ is an increasing sequence.

Pick $\epsilon = A - Q \gt 0$. Then since $D(k)$ converges to $A$, there is $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $$ k \ge N \implies | D(k) - A | \lt \epsilon  \iff D(k) \in ( A - \epsilon , A + \epsilon  )   $$

Now if we substitute for $\epsilon $ we get $$ n \ge N \implies D(k) \in ( Q , 2A - Q) \implies D(k) \gt Q $$

So your set is definitely bounded by $N$.

Comment: Actually what I need is to prove that the set of $k$ such that $D(k) \leq Q < A$, i.e., $\{k| D(k) \leq Q < A \}$ is bounded and not that the sequence $D(k)$ is bounded.

Comment: @Mai09el: My bad. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the renewed answer. But this is only mean that the set is only bounded from below. we can not conclude for the upper bound.

Comment: Set is bounded below by $ 0 $ anyway since it is a subset of $\Bbb N$. We've just proved that it is bounded above by $N$